# Why do I get such strange results for time series analysis?

Tags: python, statistics, time-series, statsmodels

I'm trying to build a model to predict the number of daily orders for a delivery cafe. Here is the data,

[image: Plotted series]

Here you can see two major peaks: they are holidays -- Feb 14 and Mar 8, respectively. Also, you can see an obvious seasonality with the period of 7: people order more at the weekend and less at working days.

Dickey-Fuller test shows that the series is not stationary with the p-value = `0.152`
Then I decided to apply the Box-Cox transformation because the deviation looks uneven. After that, Dickey-Fuller test's p-value is `0.222`, but transformed series now looks like a sinoid,

[image: Box-Cox transformed series]

Then I applied a seasonal difference like this:

```py
data["counts_diff"] = data.counts_box - data.counts_box.shift(7)
plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))
sm.tsa.seasonal_decompose(data.counts_diff[7:]).plot()
p_value = sm.tsa.stattools.adfuller(data.counts_diff[7:])[1]
```

Now p-value is about `10e-5` and the series is stationary

Then I plotted ACF and PACF to choose initial parameters to grid search,

[image: ACF/PACF]

Common sense and the rules I know told me to choose,

```
Q = 1
q = 4
P = 3
p = 6

d = 0
D = 1
```

The code for model finding:

```py
ps = range(0, p+1)
d=0
qs = range(0, q+1)
Ps = range(0, P+1)
D=1
Qs = range(0, Q+1)

parameters_list = []

for p in ps:
    for q in qs:
        for P in Ps:
            for Q in Qs:
                parameters_list.append((p,q,P,Q))
len(parameters_list)

%%time
from IPython.display import clear_output
results = []
best_aic = float("inf")

i = 1
for param in parameters_list:
    print("counting {}/{}...".format(i, len(parameters_list)))
    i += 1
    try:
        model=sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(data.counts_diff[7:], order=(param[0], d, param[1]), 
                                        seasonal_order=(param[2], D, param[3], 7)).fit(disp=-1)

    except ValueError:
        print('wrong parameters:', param)
        continue
    except LinAlgError:
        print('LU decomposition error:', param)
        continue
    finally:
        clear_output()

    aic = model.aic
    if aic < best_aic:
        best_model = model
        best_aic = aic
        best_param = param
    results.append([param, model.aic])
```

After grid search, I get this,

[image: Model]

But when I plot it, it shows a constant line at the zero,

[image: Fitted data]

Residuals are non-biased, have no trend and are not auto-correlated,

[image: Residuals]

The code for plotting is here:

```py
# inverse Box-Cox transformation
def invboxcox(y, lmbda):
    if lmbda == 0:
        return np.exp(y)
    else:
        return np.exp(np.log(lmbda*y+1) / lmbda)

data["model"] = invboxcox(best_model.fittedvalues, lmbda)
plt.figure(figsize(15,5))
plt.ylabel('Orders count')
data.counts.plot()
#pylab.show()
data.model.plot(color='r')
plt.ylabel('Model explanation')
pylab.show()
```

If I uncomment the line, the plot looks as follows,

[image: Different output]

What am I missing? Should I consider the sinoid shape of the transformed series? And why is the scale so different?

Also, the code,

```py
data["model"] = invboxcox(best_model.fittedvalues, lmbda)  
plt.figure(figsize(15,5))  
(data.counts_diff + 1).plot()  
#pylab.show()  
data.model.plot(color='r')  
pylab.show()
```

plots two fairly similar plots,

[image: Similar plots]

So, AFAIK, the problem is somewhere in the reverse transformations.

Comment: Can you provide some of the data itself? As an aside: the BoxCox transformation (including an inverse) is available in `statsmodels.base.transform`.

Comment: Yes, you can find it here: https://dropmefiles.com/Ac2rw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's first import the essentials, load the data and transform the series,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels.base.transform import BoxCox

# Load data
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)

# Transformation
box_cox = BoxCox()
y, lmbda = box_cox.transform_boxcox(df['counts'])
```

After Box-Cox transforming your series, I test it for a unit root,

```
>>>print(sm.tsa.kpss(y)[1])
0.0808334102754407
```

And,

```
>>>print(sm.tsa.adfuller(y)[1])
0.18415817136548102
```

While not entirely stationary according to the ADF test, the KPSS test is not in agreement. Visual inspection seems to suggest it may be stationary 'enough'. Let's consider a model,

```
df['counts'] = y

model = sm.tsa.SARIMAX(df['counts'], None, (1, 0, 1), (2, 1, 1, 7))
result = model.fit(method='bfgs')
```

And,

```
>>>print(result.summary())
Optimization terminated successfully.
         Current function value: -3.505128
         Iterations: 33
         Function evaluations: 41
         Gradient evaluations: 41
                                 Statespace Model Results                                
=========================================================================================
Dep. Variable:                            counts   No. Observations:                  346
Model:             SARIMAX(1, 0, 1)x(2, 1, 1, 7)   Log Likelihood                1212.774
Date:                           Wed, 24 Jul 2019   AIC                          -2413.549
Time:                                   13:37:19   BIC                          -2390.593
Sample:                               07-01-2018   HQIC                         -2404.401
                                    - 06-11-2019                                         
Covariance Type:                             opg                                         
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ar.L1          0.8699      0.052     16.691      0.000       0.768       0.972
ma.L1         -0.5811      0.076     -7.621      0.000      -0.731      -0.432
ar.S.L7        0.0544      0.056      0.963      0.335      -0.056       0.165
ar.S.L14       0.0987      0.060      1.654      0.098      -0.018       0.216
ma.S.L7       -0.9520      0.036    -26.637      0.000      -1.022      -0.882
sigma2      4.385e-05   2.44e-06     17.975      0.000    3.91e-05    4.86e-05
===================================================================================
Ljung-Box (Q):                       34.12   Jarque-Bera (JB):                68.51
Prob(Q):                              0.73   Prob(JB):                         0.00
Heteroskedasticity (H):               1.57   Skew:                             0.08
Prob(H) (two-sided):                  0.02   Kurtosis:                         5.20
===================================================================================

Warnings:
[1] Covariance matrix calculated using the outer product of gradients (complex-step).
```

The Ljung-Box result seems to suggest the residuals do not exhibit auto-correlation - which is good! Let's inverse transform the data and the results, and plot the fit,

```
# Since the first 7 days were back-filled
y_hat = result.fittedvalues[7:]

# Inverse transformations
y_hat_inv = pd.DataFrame(box_cox.untransform_boxcox(y_hat, lmbda),
                         index=y_hat.index)

y_inv = pd.DataFrame(box_cox.untransform_boxcox(y, lmbda),
                     index=df.index)

# Plot fitted values with data
_, ax = plt.subplots()
y_inv.plot(ax=ax)
y_hat_inv.plot(ax=ax)

plt.legend(['Data', 'Fitted values'])
plt.show()
```

Where I get,

[image: Fitted values]

Which does not look bad at all!

Comment: You may want to use the `exog` parameter for your holiday peaks in the specification of the [`SARIMAX`](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.statespace.sarimax.SARIMAX.html) model. I have not, but it should improve your fit for those peaks a bit.

Comment: while training a model, I'm getting a warning: `Maximum number of iterations has been exceeded.`  
`Current function value: 4.494315`
`Iterations: 50`
`Function evaluations: 71`
`Gradient evaluations: 71`
But, according to your printings, the number of iterations should be less than 50. Why is it happening?

Comment: @Anton have you set `df['counts'] = y` before calling the `SARIMAX` model?

Comment: Yeah, it helped, thank you. By the way, I'm totally new in time series analysis, so could you answer a bit more questions? How did you choose the orders of the model? And what reading would you recommend to better understand this field?

Comment: @Anton I'd start with perhaps [FPP](https://otexts.com/fpp2/), maybe read Hamilton's [TSA](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Time-Analysis-James-Douglas-Hamilton/dp/0691042896) [this is really in depth and does not shun the maths], and also _practice_. I did not choose any parameters here (these are yours), but generally you'd look at the ACF/PACF values, alongside e.g. the AIC or BIC. For an algorithm, you could look at [`auto_arima`](http://www.alkaline-ml.com/pmdarima/0.9.0/modules/generated/pyramid.arima.auto_arima.html).